# C++ Templates and typeid

Tags: c++

I'm working on a entity-component system and I want to be able to retrieve a component of a given type from an entity by using this method:

```
template <class T>
T* Entity::getComponent()
{
    for( auto i = mComponents.begin(); i != mComponents.end(); i++ )
    {
        if( typeid(**i) == typeid(T) )
        {
            return static_cast<T*>(*i);
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

Where `mComponents` is an `std::vector<Component*>`, and `T` is always a derived class of `Component`

However, the if statement never evaluates as true even though the vector does contain an element of the given type. Am I doing something obviously wrong here? I dereference *i* twice to dereference the iterator and then to dereference the pointer, as T is just a class rather than a pointer to a class.

Comment: Not an answer per se, but wouldn't `dynamic_cast` be simpler in your case ?

Comment: why vector<Component *> when you have only one element to store in the vector ? Why not just store the object itself than reference. It makes things quite easy.

Comment: Is `Component` polymorphic (i.e., does it have a virtual member function)? With a polymorphic base class [I can't reproduce your issue](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f799afeef88aa443).

Comment: Does `Component` have a vtable? That is to say, does it have at least one `virtual` function? RTTI requires it, and at least the destructor of a base class should be `virtual` in any case to prevent nasty surprises. Also, be aware that polymorphic containers like this are usually a symptom of a broken design. If you need to know more about an object than that it is a `Component`, don't remember it as a `Component`.

Comment: The array holds all of the components associated with the entity. For example, I have a `PhysicsComponent` and a `RenderComponent`. These classes are derived from `Component`, and when I want to access a particular component of the entity I can call `ent->getComponent<PhysicsComponent>();`  and it would ideally return the pointer I need.

It doesn't have any virtual functions - I will try adding one.

Comment: Adding a virtual destructor fixed the issue, works like a charm now. Thanks!

Comment: (could use a range-based for)

Comment: If you are using RTTI for application logic, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: What would you suggest is a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTTI is intended for use only with polymorphic classes (those that have a virtual function in the base class).

By adding the 'virtual' keyword in front of the destructor of your base class, RTTI will be able to resolve the correct type in the vector.

Comment: And in that case `typeid` is not needed, instead if you use `dynamic_cast` instead of `static_cast`, it returns `nullptr` if the types do not match.